# Backpress in Jetpack Compose resets the status of the previous screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently migrating my old Android app (based on xml-views) to Jetpack Compose. I use a Single Activity for all my composables (views). I use a NavController to navigate. There is something that is not clear to me:

In classic xml views, when you scroll or enter something in a text field on a particular screen for example, and you open a new Activity, and you press the backbutton, the scroll position and the text entry on the previous screen is still visible. In Compose, the screen is reset to its starting position when pressing backbutton. For some screens this is not a problem, but for others it is. Can someone help me how to solve this in Compose?

Comment: Is the entered data cleared or only the scroll position?

Comment: The entered dat is cleared…

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)